# Cannot Reindex "Product Prices" In Magento

Tags: php, sql, magento, indexing, magento-1.9

I can't re-index the "Product Prices" in Magento. It gives me an error:

> There was a problem with reindexing process.

The problem comes from the below code.

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` SELECT `inner`.`entity_id`, `inner`.`customer_group_id`, `inner`.`website_id`, `inner`.`tax_class_id`, `inner`.`orig_price`, `inner`.`price`, `inner`.`min_price`, MAX(inner.max_price) AS `max_price`, `inner`.`tier_price`, `inner`.`base_tier` FROM (SELECT e.entity_id AS `entity_id`, pi.customer_group_id AS `customer_group_id`, cw.website_id AS `website_id`, pi.tax_class_id AS `tax_class_id`, pi.price AS `orig_price`, pi.final_price AS `price`, pi.final_price AS `min_price`, pi.final_price AS `max_price`, pi.tier_price AS `tier_price`, pi.tier_price AS `base_tier` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
     LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `l` ON l.parent_id = e.entity_id
     INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `ce` ON ce.entity_id = l.product_id
     INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price_idx` AS `pi` ON ce.entity_id = pi.entity_id
     INNER JOIN `core_website` AS `cw` ON pi.website_id = cw.website_id
     INNER JOIN `core_store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.website_id = cw.website_id AND cw.default_group_id = csg.group_id
     INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON csg.default_store_id = cs.store_id AND cs.store_id != 0
     CROSS JOIN `cataloginventory_stock` AS `cis`
     LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `cisi` ON cisi.stock_id = cis.stock_id AND cisi.product_id = ce.entity_id
     LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tad_status.store_id = 0
     LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id
     INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `ciss` ON ciss.product_id = e.entity_id AND ciss.website_id = cw.website_id WHERE (e.type_id='configurable') AND (ciss.stock_status = 1) ORDER BY IF(IF(cisi.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND cisi.manage_stock = 0, 1, cisi.is_in_stock), 1, 0) DESC, pi.final_price ASC, pi.price ASC) AS `inner` GROUP BY `inner`.`entity_id`,
        `inner`.`customer_group_id`,
        `inner`.`website_id` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `orig_price` = VALUES(`orig_price`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`), `base_tier` = VALUES(`base_tier`), `group_price` = VALUES(`group_price`), `base_group_price` = VALUES(`base_group_price`)
```

This gives me error:

> 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I understand its saying that I'm putting in more values than there are columns on the table, but I don't understand how. I looked all over the internet and I've tried everything people suggested, but no avail.

How do I fix this? Is there a syntax error somewhere in that query? This indexing error caused all the products on my website to not show up any more.

Comment: This question has an answer, now deleted, that referred to [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7728/reindex-price-issue-value-list-does-not-match-column-list).